# I need to know whether my sentence tone is correct for a Software Product

Tags: grammaticality, business-language, tone

> You recently made an offline purchase, and the payment methods associated with that subscription have been dissociated. So update your payment method in our Payment portal.

This is the statement I am displaying to the user. I need to know whether my statement is clear and proper to my audience and at the same time, it should be in a proper tone. Can anyone clarify me on that and in case if it is not meeting the standards, suggest me some alternatives.

Comment: You're telling customers online that they bought something offline? The purchase did not go through, so they did not make the purchase that they tried to. *There was an issue to address*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it could be a little clearer.... I don't like the word "dissassociated", for instance. Perhaps consider: "You recently made an offline purchase, **however** the payment methods associated with **your subscription/account have expired**. Please update your payment method **via** our Payment portal, here."

Comment: The thing is,the payment methods are not expired we just delete them. Also i wish not to enclose to the users that i have deleted his previous payment method

Comment: This is a bizarre way to run a business - you're deleting details but not telling the user? In many countries there is a legal requirement to tell people what data you hold on them. This is getting very off topic, but it seems you need to consult a lawyer or other expert, and then update your message to properly explain to users what is happening.

Comment: @StuartF we don't even store the payment details only the necessary details which every site does. And dissociating them is not illegal. So please if you can help contribute some